# what is the implied volatility on a basket of options

Tags: option-pricing, basket

If I have 4 optionable stocks A,B,C,D and each different implied volatilies,IV-A,IV-B,IV-C,IV-D.  How do get the implied volatility for a basket option on A,B,C,D where the basket weights are w-A=.6, w-B=.3, w-C=.09,w-D=.01
?

Comment: I think the better question is : How to extract the basket implied volatility surface? Below a paper I find very easy to comprehend and useful to start with.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should not just ask what the implied vol is of a basket of equity derivatives but you should aim to generate a volatility surface. A spot implied vol gives you nothing to work with. What you need is an implied vol surface in order to understand the smile and skew effects when you quote basket options in the market and/or as price taker. Take a look at the following to get started:

http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/100826qu.pdf

http://relativity.phys.lsu.edu/postdocs/matt/papers/sv.pdf

Comment: nice pdfs! can  you let me know where the derivation for this comes from?: S(P, Q ) = EQ (ln Q − ln P)

Comment: Implicit in those well-chosen PDFs is the point that cointegration matters a lot for baskets.  That is to say, the volatility of a basket cannot be inferred from the dynamics of its components alone.  The very minimum you can work with is a set of volatilities and a "constant" correlation matrix with the same value $\rho$ for all off-diagonal elements.  But the PDFs are more advanced.

Comment: @Brian B, good points made. And yes, a constant correlation matrix is the absolute minimum to extract the basket implied vol.

Comment: @Nikos, sorry but which part are you referring to?

Comment: @Freddy page 59 of your first pdf

Comment: @Nikos, it is a penalty function, however key here is that it is based on the relative entropy function, which is another name for the Kullback–Leibler divergence. It measures the difference between two probability distributions, in this case the risk-neutral PDF and historical PDF. It needs to be minimized in order to derive the risk neutral PDF.

Comment: @Freddy ah thanks mate, did you learn that stats stuff on the job or  have to take courses in your free time?

Comment: @Nikos, learned similar stuff back in grad school a long time ago so I admit I myself need to look up stuff from time to time, which is one of the purposes to be active on this site (to keep my brain cells fresh and to learn).

Comment: @Freddy yeah, I find this site great that practical things experiments with R makes things fun again!